# The count only increment upto 1. It doesn't count more than one.Language is python

Tags: python, count, increment

```
a=input("enter string: ")
count=0
if 'emma' in a:
    count=count+1
else:
    print("not found")
print("no of emmas in string:"+count)
```

Comment: Why should it count more than 1? You don't have a loop, so it only executes once.

Comment: what is the problem ? if you run it only once then you can't get bigger value. You didn't show what data you use and what result you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.count` on the string instead

```
a=input("enter string: ")
print("no of emmas in string: {} ".format(a.count('emma')))
```

Output:

```
enter string: emma emma
no of emmas in string: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=input("enter string: ")
print(a.count('emma'))
```